# R- textminig with tm packages

Tags: r, loops, keyword, tm

I want to use the tm packakes, so  I have created the next code:

```
x<-inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(docs,
                          list(dictionary = c("survive", "survival"))))
```

I need to find any word beginning with "surviv" in the text, such as to include words like "survival" "survivor" "survive" and others. Is there any way to write that condition - words begining with "surviv"- in the code?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is creating a general `DocumentTermMatrix` and then filtering it to keep only rows which start with `surviv` using `startsWith`.

```
corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(c("survival", "survivance", "survival",
                               "random", "yes", "survive")))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp)
inspect(tdm[startsWith(rownames(tdm), "surv"),])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stem the words with stemDocument. Then you need to look only for surviv and survivor as these are the stem words you are looking for. Using and expanding the list of words from @AshOfFire

```
my_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(c("survival", "survivance", "survival",
                               "random", "yes", "survive", "survivors", "surviving")))
my_corpus <- tm_map(my_corpus, stemDocument)
my_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(my_corpus, control = list(dictionary = c("surviv", "survivor")))
inspect(my_dtm)

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 8, terms: 2)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 6/10
Sparsity           : 62%
Maximal term length: 8
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs surviv survivor
   1      1        0
   2      1        0
   3      1        0
   4      0        0
   5      0        0
   6      1        0
   7      0        1
   8      1        0
```

p.s. only do `x <- inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(docs, .....)` if you want to get the first 10 rows and 10 columns in your x variable.